# Python help me in returning the corresponding index of this list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two distinct columns on a csv file one for numbers (values may occur twice or more times) and the other for links.each row on the file represent a different element

I added them into two lists

```
numbers=[8,7,9,4.3,4.8,5,........]
Links=["Link1","Link2","Link3",........]
```

I need to iterate over the elements of the numbers list and if an element is <  5  i need to open the corresponding link (that would be the link placed on the analogous index position on the Links list)

How can i achieve this ? I'm thinking in something like:

For i in numbers
If an element in numbers <5
return the index of that
element and store to variable
*inspect*

```
    selenium.get Links[inspect]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a for loop to get both indices and values. A plain `for i in numbers:` loop doesn't give you the index of each number, just the number itself, so you can't return the index looping that way. The following code should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.BrowserName(executable_path = "path/to/driver")
numbers=[8, 7, 9, 4.3, 4.8, 5]
Links= [ "Link1", "Link2", "Link3", "Link4", "Link5", "Link6"]
for index, value in enumerate(numbers):
    if value < 5:
        driver.get(Links[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip and tuple to make tuples that each one contains a number and a link and then iterate on it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
web_driver = webdriver.BrowserName(executable_path = "path/to/driver")
for each_element in tuple(zip(numbers, Links)):
    if each_element[0] < 5:
        web_driver.get(each_element[1])
```

Or:

```
from selenium import webdriver
web_driver = webdriver.BrowserName(executable_path = "path/to/driver")
for each_element in [i for i in tuple(zip(numbers, Links)) if i[0] < 5]:
    web_driver.get(each_element[1])
```